# UIActivityViewController won't share xlsx file

Tags: ios, share, xlsx, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to share and *XLSX* via email using `UIActivityViewController` but when it just opens an empty email with no attachments.
When I try to add *PDF* and *XLSX* files - it opens an email with the *PDF* file attached - but no *XLSX* file...

Here's the code:

```
NSMutableArray *itemsToShare = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[itemsToShare addObject:pdfNSDATA];
[itemsToShare addObject:xlsxNSDATA];
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting the items as file URLs to your array like so:

```
NSURL *urlToPDF = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToPDF]; //pathToPDF is an nsstring with a path to your file
NSURL *urlToXSLX = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToXSLX]; //So is  

NSMutableArray *itemsToShare = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[itemsToShare addObject:urlToPDF];
[itemsToShare addObject:urlToXSLX];
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Of course you'll need to save the NSData to the file system in order to be able to do this. You can use NSData's `writeToURL:atomically` to achieve this.

Comment: will the files be deleted after I leave the app? I don't want to keep the files on the system.